# Fitting string/int in a specific format

Tags: c++

my question is editing at the input part not directly enter 1234, instead enter a number format like this D-C0-1234-5 and capture 1234 for calculation.

and I had tried printf function to fit the char and num between "-", but it cannot capture the num that I want. Is there any function that can deal with this situation?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <cmath>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    double a = 11.7 * pow(10, -6);
    double L;
    double increase_length, total_length;
    int temp_difference = 0;

    cout << "My student number is : "; **// my problem here**
    cin >> L;

    cout << endl << "Initial Length : " << L << " meters" << endl << endl;

    printf("%26s%17s\n", "Length", "Total");
    printf("%s%16s%17s\n", "Temperature", "Increase", "Length");
    printf("%10s%19s%17s\n", "(Celsius)", "(in meters)", "(in meters)");
    printf("%10s%18s%17s\n", "-----------", "-----------", "-----------");

    while(temp_difference <= 50)
    {
        increase_length = a * L * temp_difference;
        total_length = L + increase_length;

        printf("%7d%20.4f%18.4f\n", temp_difference, increase_length, total_length);

        temp_difference = temp_difference + 5;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: additional, it is a program that calculates the temperature in a table, I had already test my code by normally enter 1234 etc., it seems no problem.

Comment: If you want to read in something that complex, your best bet is likely to simply read in a whole line of input as a string, then parse and validate it. You _could_create a custom class, then overload `>>` for it, but the first method is more straightforward.

Comment: FYI, [`std::getline`](https://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/getline/) may be helpful for you, especially if you use a custom delimiter (say `'-'`) instead of the usual newline.

Comment: Are your student numbers actually floating point, such 3.14159?  In my experience, student numbers are unsigned integers.

Comment: According to your code, you are using the student number to convert to temperatures.  Strange.

Comment: I would change the prompt to `"Enter initial length:"`, and forget about the student ID since you don't use student ID in your program.

Comment: Read `"D-C0-1234-5"` into a `std::string`, create a `stringstream` from the string, and then read from the stringstream using `getline` with a delimiter of `'-'` attempting conversion of the substring to `int` (or `unsigned`) with `stoi()` and take the value of the first conversion that succeeds. (you can also process the string directly alternating  `.find_first_not_of()` and `.find_first_of()` along with `.substr()` to extract between each `'-'`)

Comment: yes...it is a little bit strange, still thanks for the reply from you guys.  David reference is helpful for me, I had done what I want, Thanks again!